# Swift: How to interrupt a sort routine

Tags: multithreading, sorting, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchworkitem

I want to give users the ability to stop a sorting routine if it takes too long.

I tried to use DispatchWorkItem.cancel. However, this does not actually stop processes that have already started.

```
let myArray = [String]() // potentially 230M elements!
...
workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
    let result = myArray.sorted()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print ("done")
    }
}
```

// if process is too long, user clicks "Cancel" =>
workItem.cancel() // does not stop sort

How can I kill the workItem's thread?

I don't have access to the sorted routine, therefore I cannot insert tests to check if current thread is in "cancelled" status...

Answer (score 0):

As you have deduced, one simply cannot kill a work item without periodically checking [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780829-iscancelled) and manually performing an early exit if it is set.

There are two options:

1. You can used [`sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted), test for `isCancelled` there, throwing an error if it is canceled. That achieves the desired early exit.

   That might look like:

   ```
   func cancellableSort() -> DispatchWorkItem {
       var item: DispatchWorkItem!
       item = DispatchWorkItem() {
           let unsortedArray = (0..<10_000_000).shuffled()
           let sortedArray = try? unsortedArray.sorted { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
               if item.isCancelled {
                   throw SortError.cancelled
               }
               return obj1 < obj2
           }
           // do something with your sorted array
           item = nil
       }
       DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: item)
       return item
   }
   ```

   Where

   ```
   enum SortError: Error {
       case cancelled
   }
   ```

   Be forewarned that even in release builds, this can have a dramatic impact on performance. So you might want to benchmark this.
2. You could just write your own sort routine, inserting your own test of `isCancelled` inside the algorithm. This gives you more control over where precisely you perform the test (i.e., you might not want to do it for every comparison, but rather at some higher level loop within the algorithm, thereby minimizing the performance impact). And given the number of records, this gives you a chance to pick an algorithm best suited for your data set.

Obviously, when benchmarking these alternatives, make sure you test optimized/release builds so that your results are not skewed by your build settings.

As an aside, you might considering using `Operation`, too, as its handling of cancelation is more elegant, IMHO. Plus you can have a dedicated object for the sort operation, which is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Rob; I will use sorted(by:) with a isCancelled test embedded in each comparison. It is not clear to me how Operation cancelation handling would be more elegant: I would still need to add an Operation.isCancelled test in every comparison, wouldn't I? More generally, I am surprised that there is no "kill pid" method to simply kill a thread...

Comment: Re `Operation` elegance, it’s a minor thing, but I hate the silliness one needs to make `DispatchWorkItem` cancelable (the declaration of the item as a var first, then instantiate, then check `isCancelled`, and finally, making sure to set `item` to `nil` to at the end or else it’s won’t get released). With `Operation` subclass, (a) everything is wrapped up in that separate object in the spirit of SRP; and (b) you don’t have to worry about that strong reference cycle caused by checking `isCancelled` in `DispatchWorkItem` closure. It’s minor, but I just find `DispatchWorkItem` approach kludgy.

Comment: Re no “kill pid” equivalent for threads, I agree that would be nice, but the issue is that unless you unwind all of the memory management calls, it would leak memory. It does all the necessary memory unwinding if your routine throws an error or employs other “early exit” approaches within the routine. But when one just kills an entire pid, it just discards all memory associated with that process, but that approach won’t work for a single thread in a multithreaded app.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!